# Why can't single particle states be taken up by more than one particle in the Fermi Dirac Distribution?

Tags: solid-state-physics

In Ashcroft, a single particle state is specified by k which is the wave vector of a single electron's wave function (without considering spin). Pauli Exclusion Principle says that a single electron can only take one k value (2 if spin is considered). But this doesn't make sense to me, aren't single particle states called "single particle states" because they can be independently taken up by separate individual electrons ? Instead if it were that the state of a system can only support one particle then it would have made sense. Consider an electron at one end of a giant piece of metal and another at the other extreme end. What prevents the other electron from having the same single particle state (value of k) as the first electron which could be several meters away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In k-space, electron states have a well-defined momentum, but they are delocalized in space. So, in theory, an electron wavefunction can extend over the entire giant piece of metal. After all, the wavefunction with a single k value is a sine wave (which extends infinitely in each direction). All the electrons which are “competing” for states are delocalized, so they indeed exclude each other.

Comment: It makes sense now that you have said it, but wow that is crazy !!

Comment: @Examination12345 it’s counterintuitive for sure!